# How to find a maximum chroma value in the OKLCH color space for given hue and lightness?

Tags: color-space, lab-color-space, oklch

Chroma value varies for different hues, and I want to understand how I can find the maximum value that is displayable for the given hue and lightness programmatically.

I saw a couple of color pickers that can limit the selection visually, but I don't have access to their code, but anyway, I think it should be possible somehow.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an elegant solution but if you can convert from `Oklch` to an `RGB` space, you can increment the chroma until the conversion results in an RGB that contains a value outside of the 0-1 range.

For example, with [my Unicolour library](https://github.com/waacton/Unicolour) I can do this in C#:

```cs
const double increment = 0.001;

var chroma = 0.0;
while (true)
{
    // by default assumes sRGB display
    var unicolour = new Unicolour(ColourSpace.Oklch, 0.5, chroma, 285);
    if (!unicolour.IsInDisplayGamut)
    {
        chroma -= increment;
        break;
    }
    
    chroma += increment;
}

Console.WriteLine(chroma); // 0.292
```